# Brisker seforim on chullin

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, lomdus, chulin-tractate, brisk

I want to learn the style of brisker lomdus in conjunction with chullin. What are some good seforim  for this? I asking specifically an analysis connected to the daf

Comment: Daf>eyn mishpat>rambam>brisk.

Comment: Very funny @Dr.Shmuel